# Calculate percentage of a value in a column when count is given

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with values below

```
id     name      approved      count
3      az        1             10
3      az        0             5
2      az        1             10
2      az        0             5
3      bz        1             10
3      bz        0             5
2      bz        1             10
2      bz        0             5
```

I need to calculate the % of approved =1 with my final view that shows

```
id     name      Rate     
3      az        66.66            
3      bz        66.66            
2      az        66.66          
2      bz        66.66
```

Where rate is (10/15)*100 i.e (count of approved = 1/sum of count for that id,name combination)*100

Comment: And have you tried... anything?

Comment: I tried [rate]=100*(countof)/sum(countof) but that was obviously wrong . . I tried using 'case' but couldn't get it done either.

I did the calculation before, but the table i had then was different and did not have the count column.

Comment: Please post DDL,DML Of the tables involved.Having this info helps others to quickly repro your issue and asnwer better.Below is some sample which might help you understand.  

**--sample data**  
`create table #t1
(
id int
)

insert into #t1
values
(1),
(2),
(1)
`    
**my current query/what i have tried:**   
`select id,count(*) as cnt from
#t1
group by id`  

**my current result:**  
`id cnt
1  2
2  1`

**my expected result:**
`id cnt
1  2
2  1
1  2`

Comment: Thank you! I'll keep that in mind when i ask a question again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way using conditional aggregation

```
SELECT id,
       NAME,
       Isnull(Sum(CASE WHEN approved = 1 THEN [count] END) / Sum([count] * 1.0) * 100,0)
FROM  your_table
GROUP BY id, NAME
```

`* 1.0` is used to avoid *integer division*

Comment: Just a quick followup. This gives me a null value when there is an id with only 0 approved. Is there a way to just get the rate as 0 then instead of a null?

Comment: @beginnerdscientist - use `Isnull` or `Coalesce` function.. updated by answer

Answer (score 0):

```
 select id,name,
 sum(case when approved=1 then round(cast(count as float)/15*100,2) end) 'Rate'
  from Your_Table
  group by id,name
```

Answer (score 0):

If you also want to return the detail of each line.

```
    create table #t(id int,name varchar(10),approved bit,count int)
    insert into #t
    select 3,'az',1,10 union all
    select 3,'az',0,5 union all
    select 2,'az',1,10 union all
    select 2,'az',0,5 union all
    select 3,'bz',1,10 union all
    select 3,'bz',0,5 union all
    select 2,'bz',1,10 union all
    select 2,'bz',0,5 
    select * from (
       select *,sum(case when approved=1 then count else 0 end )over()*1.0/sum(count)over() as perc from #t
    ) as t where t.approved=1 order by id desc
```

```
+----+------+----------+-------+----------------+
| id | name | approved | count | perc           |
+----+------+----------+-------+----------------+
| 3  | az   | 1        | 10    | 0.666666666666 |
| 3  | bz   | 1        | 10    | 0.666666666666 |
| 2  | bz   | 1        | 10    | 0.666666666666 |
| 2  | az   | 1        | 10    | 0.666666666666 |
+----+------+----------+-------+----------------+
```